# Make a phone call from app when user presses the call button (override default behaviour)

Tags: blackberry

I have a listfield in my app showing a list of contacts. I would like to call the selected contact when the user presses the green call button (instead of the default behaviour which launches the phone call log app).

This means there are 2 issues:
1) can I intercept the green call button?
2) how can I make the call from the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before answering the question, it is assumed that you are keeping track of the currently selected item in the list, and you have a way of finding the related phone number.

1) **Intercept the call button**
You need to implement the `keyDown(int, int)` method in a Manager or Screen, catch the correct keycode, and return true:

```
protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time)
{
    // check for the green phone button
    if (keycode == 1114112)
    {
        /* 
         * Place your custom calling code here.
         */

        return true; // indicates that this method has consumed the keypress
    }
    else
    {
        return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
    }
}
```

(based on answer given at http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Can-Over-ride-Call-Button-using-api-Issue-Shows-Context-Menu-on/m-p/252554/highlight/true#M41073)

2) **Make a phone call**
You need to `Invoke()` the phone app, passing it the phone number you wish to call:

```
    PhoneArguments callArgs = new PhoneArguments(
        PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, "+27 83 111 1234");
    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, callArgs);
```

---

So combining gives this code:

```
protected boolean keyDown(int keycode, int time)
{
    // check for the green phone button
    if (keycode == 1114112)
    {
        // get phone number - you must write this yourself
        String number = selectedContact.getNumber();  // assume some method here depending on your solution

        // make the call
        PhoneArguments callArgs = new PhoneArguments(
            PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, number);
        Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, callArgs);

        // indicate that the key has been processed
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return super.keyDown(keycode, time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Blackberry documentation:

> net.rim.blackberry.api.phone
>
> public final class Phone extends
>   Object
>
> This class provides the following:
>
> ```
> * Advanced utilities for interaction with the Phone
> ```
>
> application. You can use the methods
>   in this class for finer manipulation
>   of the Phone application. For example,
>   injecting DTMF tones into active
>   calls.
>       * Access multiple lines on the device.
>       * Adding data to the incoming and active call screens, if supported.
>
> Multi-line examples
>
> Example A: Switching a line
>
> 1. Create a class that extends MultiLineListener.
>
>    public class MultiLineAction extends MultiLineListener
> 2. Register the class as a PhoneListener.
>
>    Phone.addPhoneListener(this);
> 3. Implement the MultiLineListener callbacks so that the app can be
>      notified of switching results.
>
>    public void setPreferredLineFailure(int lineId)
>         {
>             _screen.popupMessage("Switching failed");
>         }
>         public void setPreferredLineSuccess(int lineId)
>         {
>          _screen.popupMessage("Switching to " + Phone.getLineNumber(lineId) + "
>      completed" );
>         }
> 4. Invoke Phone.setPreferredLine().
>
>    Phone.setPreferredLine( Phone.getLineIds()[0]);
>
> Example B: Initiate an outgoing call
>
> 1. Invoke Phone.initiateCall.
>
>    Phone.initiateCall(Phone.getLineIds()[0],
>      "5195550123");
> 2. Deregister the class from the phone listener before the application
>      is closed.
>
>    Phone.removePhoneListener(this);
>
> Category:
>       Signed: This element is only accessible by signed applications. If
>   you intend to use this element, please
>   visit
>   http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning
>   to obtain a set of code signing keys.
>   Code signing is only required for
>   applications running on BlackBerry
>   smartphones; development on BlackBerry
>   Smartphone Simulators can occur
>   without code signing. Since:
>       BlackBerry API 4.0.0

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/